# Change connection used on runtime

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I hope you can help me (us). I'm working on a API project which have two databases :

`Production DB : api.myapp.fr`

`Testing DB : test.api.myapp.fr`

Theses two databases are writable by the user.

When a user call our API, he can set the authorization header whichever he needs. For example :

`Authorization: s_0`

Will perform  operations on `api.myapp.fr`  and

`Authorization: s_t_0`

Will perform operations on  `test.api.myapp.fr` .

My question is : How can I do that with sails ?

Actually, I have a policie which check if the user is using a production key or a testing key, and I override the default models with the one for testings purposes, like this :

```
if (!is_production) {
    req.session.isProd = false;
    req.session.logs.environment = "test";

    User = UserTest;
    Payment = PaymentTest;
    PayzenStatus = PayzenStatusTest;
    Transaction = TransactionTest;
    Card = CardTest;
    Doc = DocTest;
}
```

But you can see the problem if a user makes a test request and then a production request, the models are still the tests ones...

I use my models in services and policies, therefor I can't do

```
req.models = {};
// If not in production, use the test models
if (!is_production) {
    req.session.isProd = false;
    req.session.logs.environment = "test";

    req.models.User = UserTest;
    req.models.Payment = PaymentTest;
    req.models.PayzenStatus = PayzenStatusTest;
    req.models.Transaction = TransactionTest;
    req.models.Card = CardTest;
    req.models.Doc = DocTest;
}
// Otherwise use the production models
 else {
    req.models.User = User;
    req.models.Payment = Payment;
    req.models.PayzenStatus = PayzenStatus;
    req.models.Transaction = Transaction;
    req.models.Card = Card;
    req.models.Doc = Doc;
}
```

If you have any idea on how ton achieve this (whatever the way, we can still perform deep changes in our code), I would be really happy to ear it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two different ways of doing this.

First you could set an environment variable on your production host and check that environment variable to see if you are running in prod.  If you are running in prod then use the URI to the production database.

Secodonly, which is probably the better way of doing this creating a `config.js` file that allows you to read environment variables.  What I do for all my apps is set environment variables for connection info to databases and API keys.  When running locally/testing I have some defaults in my app but when they environment variables are set they are read and used.  So set the environment variable in production to point to your production databases.

The `config.js` file Im posting below contains references to VCAP, which assumes you are running on Cloud Foundry.

config.js

```
var VCAP_SERVICES = process.env["VCAP_SERVICES"],
    vcapServices;

if (VCAP_SERVICES) {
    vcapServices = JSON.parse(VCAP_SERVICES);
}

function getEnv(propName, defaultValue) {
    if (process.env[propName]) {
        return process.env[propName];
    } else {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

module.exports = function() {
    return {
        getEnv : getEnv,
        couchDbURL: function() {
            // Default to a local couch installation for development
            if (VCAP_SERVICES) {
                return vcapServices["cloudantNoSQLDB"][0].credentials.url;
            }
            else {
                return "http://localhost:5984";
            }
        },
        couchDbName: function() {
            return getEnv("COUCHDB_NAME", "mydb");
        }
    };
};
```

app.js

```
var config = require("./config")();
console.log(config.couchDbURL());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I use a single env with a single sails running. 

I think I'll go on and create just one database with a flag for each table saying if test/prod. Even if I don't like it :(

Comment: If you are happy with the question could you accept the answer so we can close this out?